# Moving through characters in assembly

Tags: assembly

Ok, so I need to print a string backwards. If ebx is a pointer to the start of the string array, why can't I just add one to it to go to the next byte in the array, which is the 2nd character in the string?

```
PROMPT:
.ascii "Enter the string to evaluate \0"
FMT_STR:
.ascii "%s\0"
FMT_INT:
.ascii "%d\0"
FMT_CHR:
.ascii "%c\0"

.globl _main
_main:
    pushl %ebp                # save old frame ptr
movl  %esp,%ebp           # set new frame ptr & save local var space

//create local variable space
subl $100,%esp

pushl $PROMPT
call _printf

leal -4(%ebp),%ebx

pushl %ebx
call _gets

call _rprint

leave
ret

_rprint:

pushl %ebp
movl %esp,%ebp

pushl -1(%ebx)
pushl $FMT_CHR
call _printf

leave
ret
```

EDIT: I reread my notes and realized that I need to increase 8 to go to the next character in the string.

Comment: Your notes, or your reading of them, are in error.

Comment: I know, the professor I think was wrong, because ascii is 1 byte per character.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* add one to go to the second character.  But to process the characters backwards, you would:

- find the end of the string
- process the character
- back up one character
- if it is not before the buffer, go to the second step

Comment: I fixed it up. I am going to use recursion to call the characters so I can work through forwards.

Check my orig post, I am going to edit it.